# Display content from database mysql in divs depending on value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display content from MYSQL database. data1,2,3,4 can either be 1 or 0. If the value is 1, it will display content. [If it is equal to doc_typ which is either Instruction or form]. I'm trying to print out all links in which the arguments data=1 and doc_typ=instruction are true.

```
$database = array("data1", "data2","data3","data4");
foreach ($database as $data){
   $find_doc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM document WHERE $data ='1'
   AND doc_typ='Instruction' ");

   while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($find_doc){
   $id=$row['id'];
   $doc_name=$row['name'];
   $doc_url=$row['url'];
   $outputinst. = '<li><a href="'.$doc_url.'">'.$doc_name.'</a></li>';


   }
   $output='<div class="docWindow">'.$data.'
   <div id="instruction">'.$outputinst.'</div> </div>'
}
```

My table looks like id, name, url, doc_typ atm. I have 2 rows with info, (id=1 name=issues url=issues.doc doc_typ= instruction data2=1 and data4=1) and (id=2 name="action" url="action.doc/ doc_typ=instruction data1=1 and data 4=1)

Currently it will just display 1 link in first div, 2 links in second div and 3 links in third div, even though it  is supposed to be restricted to only show when 1 argument is true.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="docwindow">data1
<li><a href="issues">issues</a></li>
</div>
<div class="docwindow">data2
<li><a href="issues">issues</a></li>
<li><a href="action">action</a></li>
</div>
<div class="docwindow">data3
<li><a href="issues">issues</a></li>
<li><a href="action">action</a></li>
<li><a href="issues">issues</a></li>
</div>
<div class="docwindow">data4
<li><a href="issues">issues</a></li>
<li><a href="action">action</a></li>
<li><a href="issues">issues</a></li>
<li><a href="action">action</a></li>
</div>
```

**Edit**
 bonus question? Is it possible to replace $data in width another array before output? like ("list","form","int","div")

```
$output='<div class="docWindow">'.$data.'
<div id="instruction">'.$outputinst.'</div> </div>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
    $output='<div class="docWindow">'.$data.'
    <div id="instruction">'.$outputinst.'</div> </div>'
```

Add

```
    $outputinst = '';
```

to empty your variable

Comment: Thanks! realy simple solution thanks, it was killing me.

Answer (score 0):

Reset (initialize) the `$outputinst` variable before the while loop. Just add a `$outputinst = '';`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$database = array("data1", "data2","data3","data4");
foreach ($database as $data){
   $find_doc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM document WHERE $data ='1'
   AND doc_typ='Instruction' ");

   while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($find_doc){
       $id=$row['id'];
       $doc_name=$row['name'];
       $doc_url=$row['url'];
       $outputinst. = '<li><a href="'.$doc_url.'">'.$doc_name.'</a></li>';
   }
   $output='<div class="docWindow">'.$data.'
   <div id="instruction">'.$outputinst.'</div> </div>';
   $outputinst='';
}

?>
```